# Is Google OAuth a viable solution for this project?

Tags: php, oauth, google-oauth

At my company we use Google Apps.

I've written a dashboard application (PHP/Laravel) which is used throughout the organization. It has a custom authentication system, but I'd like to integrate it with other services we use.

The basic use case that I'm interested in is something like this: you come in to the office in the morning, sign in to your email, and you're automatically signed in to the dashboard.

I've been looking at OAuth & reading about how to implement it, but it's not clear to me that it will do what I want.

So the basic question is this: what can Google OAuth do for me?

Comment: I think you are looking for [SSO](http://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on)

Comment: @PeeHaa - I guess so. That means what I really need to know is whether or not Google's OAuth solution can function as SSO for my application. It looks like HansZ has given an answer below. I'm going to evaluate it & see where to go from here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google+ Signin which is an OpenID Connect compliant SSO mechanism built on top of OAuth. By extending your applications with OpenID Connect Resouce Provider (RP) functionality and pointing them to Google as the Provider (OP) you would achieve SSO across your applications.

For a list of OpenID Connect RP libraries/implementations that you may leverage for your applications, see: http://openid.net/developers/libraries/